# How to publish JMX stats on to a single remote server

Tags: jmx, remote-server

Lets say I have two applications/tomcats **T1** and **T2**, both of which are jmx enabled. Each of them normally would have their own URL `<serve_X>:<port_X>` to which the jmx clients would connect. I want to know if it is possible to have a single rmi-server **S1**, running on port **P1**; which can hold the statistics of both **T1 and T2**.

If so how can I figure out the context? (as all the stats are now redirected to the same url). The closest I could find on internet is [point 7 in this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/faq.html). The intent is to have a centralized location for jmx services. I am trying to figure out if there is something like a context name (as in servlets) to facilitate this.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that is rather new (compared to when the question was asked) is something like this:

**JMX `->` [Codahale Metrics](http://metrics.codahale.com/manual/core/#jmx-gauges) `->` [metrics-statsd](https://github.com/organicveggie/metrics-statsd) `->` [StatsD](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/) `->` [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/)/Reporting/Monitoring**

Basically you use StatsD to aggregate the stats and Metrics library to convert JMX to something reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I think to do this you would need to re-write the object names so that they don't clash.
The server S1 would run on P1 as you say, and for requests coming in, forward them to the respective tomcats T1 and T2.

If you have e.g. `tomacat:key1=value1` as objectname, then you could expose that on your  proxyserver S1 as `tomcat:server=T1,key1=value1` for the first real server and `tomcat:server=T2,key1=value1` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

If you end goal is ease of monitoring, or ability to combine stats, then look into  [Evident ClearStone](http://www.evidentsoftware.com/products/clearstone-for-java/)